# Editing CodePlex Source Code

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF - and Visual Studio - and I am using [Modern UI (Metro) Charts](https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) in my application with great effect. The problem I have, however, is that I need to change part of the source code to implement a particular chart into my project.

Specifically, I need to change the hard-coded height and width of the Radial Gauge Piece (part of the Radial Gauge Chart) so it can be scaled. I have even found an example of the code to do it (see below) but I can't figure out where to implement it. The original is in the `Generic.XAML` part of the download.

```
<Style x:Key="RadialGaugeChartChartAreaStyle" TargetType="chart:ChartArea">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chart:ChartArea">
                    <Grid>
                        <Viewbox Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am not looking for anyone to do this for me, just a pointer in the right direction - I'm stumped.

Comment: can you give a drawing to illustrate what you need?

Comment: Hi, I need to implement the above code into the source code of the CodePlex download. The original has the height and width hard-coded, and is available in the Generic.XAML file in the download: https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/106190 I have tried opening the DLL reference, but I can't find the Generic.XAML file in there - I'm not sure this is the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to modify the style of the chart.

If fact, it is quite simple to scale the chart with the help of `ViewBox`. All you have to do is define a `decent size` for the chart - large enough to accommodate the series, but not over-sized.

For example, if the series has four entries, you can define a `decent size` of 800 x 600 for the chart. If the series has more entries, you define a bigger size.

```
<MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart Width="800" Height="600">
    <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
        <MetroChart:ChartSeries>
        <!---->
        </MetroChart:ChartSeries>
    </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
</MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart>
```

And put it inside a `ViewBox`.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MetroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart Width="800" Height="600">
            <MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
                <MetroChart:ChartSeries
                        SeriesTitle="Errors"
                        DisplayMember="Category"
                        ValueMember="Number"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}">
                </MetroChart:ChartSeries>
            </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart.Series>
        </MetroChart:RadialGaugeChart>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

`ViewBox` can scale the chart nicely in any available space.

Comment: It feels like a workaround, but it works perfectly for now. I'll be sure to keep the ViewBox in mind for the future.

Comment: Indeed. After running the demo and resizing the window, I think each `RadialGaugePiece` has predefined maximum and minimum sizes, and the predefined sizes are _required_ by the `RadialGaugeChart` to be able to determine the number of rows. So instead of scaling each piece, it is easier to scale the chart as a whole.

Comment: I couldn't achieve my goal because I'm referencing the DDL from a VB.NET project - I don't know C Sharp - if I want to amend the source code, I'll have to either: convert the whole project over into VB (something which is beyond me at the moment), learn C Sharp, or try and implement the two together, if that's possible...